# I want to show data from two tables in a single view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two tables: one named `um_org_data` and the other `addresses`.

The problem is that I want to show the data from `um_org_data` with `addresses` where `addresses` has a foreign key `um_org_datum_id`.

Here is the code of my view in which I want to show the data from two tables together:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="span3 pull-right">
        <div class="well">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Sample text</p>
        </div> 
      </div> 

    <div class="span9">
    <h2>Organization Details</h2>

    <table class="table table-hover">
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" style="width: 200px">
            </i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Organization Name:
        </th>
        <td><%= @um_org_datum.org_name %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" style="width: 250px">
            </i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Organization Description:
        </th>
        <td><%= @um_org_datum.org_description %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" style="width: 250px">
          </i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Web Domain:
        </th>
        <td><%= @um_org_datum.webdomain %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" style="width: 200px">
          <%= fields_for :address_attributes do |p| %>
            <%= p.label 'Office Address' %><br />              
        </th>
        <td><%= p.address.offc_addr %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th col span="1" style="width: 200px">
            </i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Office Phone Number:
        </th>
        <td><%= @um_org_datum.offc_ph %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">       
       <a class="btn" href="/um_org_data" style="text-color:black">View all</a>


       </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I don't use any join query in the controller as I don't know how to use join query. If this problem needs a join query, please tell me what is the syntax and what I have to change in the view form to show attributes of both tables.

table name: `um_org_data` , attributes: `id, oeg_name, org_description, webdomain`

table name: `adrresses` , attributes: `id, offc_addr, um_org_datum_id`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you set up the associations in their respective model files?

Comment: yes i have done that... when i use to create a new data and submit it that stores in both tables seperately from one view... but dont know how to show them together in single view

Comment: from what you have explained, it looks like you have an organization which has multiple addresses. SO basically 1:M with org and addresses. Is that correct?

Comment: yes thats correct @dewdrops

Comment: Is @Mattherick's answer working for you?

Comment: noops getting error in that..

Comment: everything is fine in creating new data... name, description, webdomain, telephone goes in organization table and multiple addresses goes in addresses table... but when i try to show that both in a same view that getting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have 1:n association? Am I right?

Definitely remove the fields_for...you are not in a form!

Change this:

```
  <tr>
    <th col span="1" style="width: 200px">
      <%= fields_for :address_attributes do |p| %>
        <%= p.label 'Office Address' %><br />              
    </th>
    <td><%= p.address.offc_addr %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
```

to this:

```
  <tr>
    <th col span="1" style="width: 200px">Office Address</th>
    <%= @um_org_datum.addresses.each do |p| %>
     <td><%= p.office_addr %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
```

Check out the markup, but the logic should be clear now..

Comment: having error in that code :(

`undefined local variable or method `each' for #<#<Class:0x000000031f0f38>:0x007eff48619a38>


Extracted source (around line #37):


34:       </tr>

35:       <tr>

36:         <th col span="1" style="width: 200px">Office Address</th>

37:         <%= @um_org_datum.addresses each do |p| %>

38:          <td><%= p.offc_addr %></td>

39:         <% end %>

40:       </tr>`

Comment: I asked might be there is join query for that... as i don't use any join query, so if u can tell me the syntax then i m very much thankful to you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have the following in your models

um_org_datum

```
has_many :addresses
```

address

```
belongs_to :um_org_datum
```

Does this work?

```
  <tr>
    <th col span="1" style="width: 200px">Office Address</th>
    <%= @um_org_datum.addresses.each do |p| %>
     <td><%= p.offc_addr %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
```

Comment: noops getting error... as i posted the details in the above answer! u can check there

Comment: what if you try @um_org_datum.addresses.each, with the dot between addresses and each